# Sogou Map API is not working in HTTPS protocol

Tags: javascript, angular, maps

I am integrating Sogou Map API in angular 2 application. in my code I am calling the "onGo2mapApiLoad" function to initialize the map in this application on the browser.
I am loading the API as - https://api.go2map.com/maps/js/api_v2.5.1.js.

I could see the Map works displays properly when I access my application over http, like - localhost:4200/displayMap.html. But when deploy this code in QA server and  I access the same page over HTTPS like https://www.dev.com/displayMap.html , the map is not working.

I don't see any error in the browser console . I also could see the sogou API is getting loaded in the browser But the "onGo2mapApiLoad" is not getting called 
 to initialize the Map object .So my webpage is not showing any map.

I followed - http://map.sogou.com/api/documentation/javascript/api2.5/basics.html to understand and use Sogou map API .

After beautifying the sogou map API I could see the function  "onGo2mapApiLoad" is using http to get called .

```
             (function() {
    var $ = gts(document, "SCRIPT"),
        _, A = /^http:\/\/.*\/maps\/js\/api_v[\d\.]+\.js$/,
        B;
    for (_ = 0; _ < $.length; _++)
        if (A.test($[_].src)) {
            B = $[_]["onGo2mapApiLoad"];
            if (B) B()
        }
})()
```

Can anyone suggest me how to fix this issue.

Anyone having any experience working with Sogou Map API.

Comment: After beautifying the sogou map API I could see the function  "onGo2mapApiLoad" is using http to get called .                    (function() {
        var $ = gts(document, "SCRIPT"),
            _, A = /^http:\/\/.*\/maps\/js\/api_v[\d\.]+\.js$/,
            B;
        for (_ = 0; _ < $.length; _++)
            if (A.test($[_].src)) {
                B = $[_]["onGo2mapApiLoad"];
                if (B) B()
            }
    })()